# Tracking issue BizTalk 2016 after rename SA

Tags: biztalk, tracking, sql-server-2016, biztalk-2016

Last week I've changed the Service Account name, There was an issue with the name conventions.
It was only the Process Host of our development environment.

I have been confronted with the following problem since the adjustment.

Only the tracking of the Pipelines does work.
All the other tracking doesn't anything.

What I've done till now.

- Add renamed SA as sysadmin (old one wasn't sysadmin) into DB with the same settings as the "old" SA
- Check SQL what records are processed into the DB

  - I can only see the tracking information of the pipelines
- Check settings of all the components

  - All check boxes are on, so everything should be tracked
- BizTalk Health Monitoring

  - Run the Analyse and Run the Maintenance after analyse report, Did every 
     recommenced fix of the analyse.
- Run the query of the following post [Missing Tracking Data problem followup from previous post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michaelstephenson/archive/2010/01/12/137455.aspx)
- Created a new Tracking Host Instance (2nd) and disabled the old one.
- Adding Logging into the TDDS, after reading this article [BizTalk Tracking: best practices & troubleshooting](https://www.codit.eu/blog/2016/01/21/biztalk-tracking-best-practices-troubleshooting/)

My ideas are gone and don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Maybe try un-configuring and then re-configuring BizTalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the information, it is fortunate to solve the problem.

What I've done:

- Unconfigure BizTalk Server
- Delete all related Databases of BizTalk.
- Run Repair tool of BizTalk Server (inside MSI)
- Configure BizTalk Server
- Deploy the solutions

After done all this steps my environment was working like expected.

Answer (score 0):

So, changing a service account name is not supported and, as you have unfortunately found out, will cause problems.

The correct process is to create a **new** Account with the new name, then re-prevision the services (BizTalk Host Instances) with the new Account.  Meaning, delete the previous Host Instances and create new ones.